# Grub fails to boot Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I bought a Packard Bell Dot s netbook last week. It came with Windows 7 pre-installed, the microsoft tax.

I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10 but the installation disk complained about something I forget what.

The original installation, acording to Ubuntu 11.10 installation CD was as below, but without the sda4-6 partitions and sda2 occupied the rest of the disk, 291,xxx MiB.    As I understand things the original installation booted normaly from sda2 and if you wish to recover from the hard drive you press alt+F10 during start up and this starts "Packard Bell recovery management", presumably from sda1.

I used gparted to reduce sada3 to 151,xxx Mib and then went ahead and installed UbuntU 11.10. The resultant gparted view was as bellow.

```
Partition   File System Mount point Label   Size    used        Unused      Flags
/dev/sda1   ntfs        PQSERVICE   13.00 GiB   10.03 GiB   2.97 GiB    dflag
/dev/sda2   ntfs        SYSTEM RESERVED 100.00 MiB  33.59 MiB   66.41 MiB   boot
/dev/sda3   ntfs        Packard Bell    148.27 GiB  21.3 GiB    126.98 GiB
/dev/sda4   extended            136.72 GiB
    /dev/sda5   ext4        /       135.73 GiB  5.25 GiB    130.48 GiB
    /dev/sda6   linux swap          1011.00 MiB
```

The start up screen offers Ubuntu 11.10, a number of memory tests and last Windows 7 on sda2! When I choose this option windows falls over.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows generally does not like when we resize Windows partitions with Linux tools (like Gparted), this is why I always recommend to resize them via Windows tools when possible.

**In order to fix your current situation:**

1. Use a Windows repair disc [this way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader#Windows_Vista_or_7_or_8), until you get direct access to Windows,
2. then use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to restore your Grub menu.

Comment: Thanks LovinBuntu.   I fixed it by using the otion to run windowws 7 recovery from sda1.  The first time I tried this it fell over, like windows. But today it worked#